# Textmate: Open Selected File in the Files tab

Tags: textmate

is there a key-binding to open a selected/marked file from the from the file browser in Textmate? I.e., if I have files File1, File2, ... in Proj,
and I am currently editing File1, I can go the file browser on the right (in my case) with C-Tab and scroll down to FileN with the up/down-keys. How do I open it now?

Of course, you can always do something line ⌘-T and then type the name of the file, but if you have 100 files starting in the same way, it can be annoying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open the files in the file browser the same way you open them in Finder, with ⌘-⬇︎.

When you select multiple files (⇧-⬇︎ / ⇧-⬆︎), you can open them all at once.

Comment: that's embarrassing -- I always used ⌘-O which didn't work on TM. thanks!